# What does the Submarine do in BTD5?

Tags: bloons-td-5

It's a new tower but I haven't gotten the time to test it. What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Monkey_Sub

Placed in water, it throws darts on bloons at medium speed(1.32 times/sec). It can be upgraded to have nearly **unlimited range** (by being able to target all bloons within the radius of any other tower), **detect camo** bloons, and to launch **missiles** (with an ability able to destroy up to a ZOMG in a single blow).

This tower has one of the best power/price ratio, and is the only one able to one-shot a ZOMG.

Comment: wait i didnt know it could one-shot a ZOMG

Comment: @NukesPlus : [First Strike Capaility](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/First_Strike_Capability)

Comment: It's an upgrade that I find really helpful in the later levels once ZOMG's come in from different lanes. Taking one of them down immediately will really save you in a pinch!

Comment: I think I read from somewhere that it shoots homing darts...